# Name of command drop down list in swift

Tags: swift, command

What is the dropdown list of varibles called that shows up when you start typing in a command in swift. I'm trying to find a list of all of the words so I can search for them and get a better understanding of which commands will work better for me.

Comment: Do you mean autocomplete/documentation? You can use cmd + shift + 0 to access I think. Otherwise window -> documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's not like web. You need to use custom UITableView and segue. You can check here for your reference:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/81880/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2